# how do I show 'Do you want to delete' message box as simply way?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC 5 project. There I want to show delete message box by simple way depends on many purpose by click on a delete buttons. How can I do as below showing ?

Comment: use bootbox for this

Comment: That's a simple [JavaScript confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm).

Comment: could you please give me example by using bootbox ?

Comment: you can use confirmBox [tutorial point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_dialog_boxes.htm)

Comment: @TiesonT. Now I am using javascript confim alert, but not looking like as the image showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jQuery:

```
$(".delete").on('click touchstart',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var c = confirm("Are you shure you want to delete this?");
    if(c)
    {
        /* DO WHAT YOU WANT */
    }
});
```

Or pure JavaScript

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");

var myFunction = function() {
    var c = confirm("Are you shure you want to delete this?");
    if(c)
    {
        /* DO WHAT YOU WANT */
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

Or JavaScript inside HTML attribute `onClick` with some URL redirection to delete page:

```
<button type="button" class="delete" onClick="var c = confirm('Are you shure you want to delete this?'); if(c) window.location.href='http://yourdomain/delete.php?id=1'">Delete</button>
```

For some custom alerts, I will suggest **[SweetAlert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert)**.

Comment: Yes I am using javascript `confirm` but It showing 'localhost say: do you want to delete' like that also background screen is clickable. How can I prevent by this approach ?

Comment: Background is not clickable on confirm. That's similar like alert but with confirmation. If you want custom confirmation you must do more work on it or use just [SweetAlert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert) what support CSS and custom things. Is realy Sweet :D